# How to allow a class type in a template parameter, only if it have two base classes

Tags: c++, templates

I tried to make a template class which allow only classes that implementing two other classes as parameter.

I know there is a way to do this with the STL, like with `std::enable_if`. But I have problem to write it down, because every examples I saw use basic type like `int`, `bool`, etc.

My real question is, am I going the right way? Or this is not the good concept to use?

EDIT:

The base code is :

```
template < class resource_t >
class ResourcesManager final : public ServiceInterface, public Libraries::Observer, public Libraries::Observable
{
...
}
```

I would like "`resource_t`" be a class that inherit from class `AnOtherClassA` and `AnOtherClassB`, if no, I would like to have a compilation warning. Because right now, something in the compilation fails far below because I try to use a method that doesn't exists in "`resource_t`", I know how to solve it, but I just want to have a better warning.

Comment: `std::enable_if` will work.  You could also just use a `static_assert` in the class body.

Comment: *"class wich allow only objects"* Why do you mean by allowing objects? Allowing passing specific types to a template parameter? *"objects that implementing two other classes"* What do you mean?

Comment: I dont know about static_assert, but I really want a clean compile time solution.

Comment: I'm sorry I will correct the message, this is a class that implementing two other classes

Comment: "I dont know about static_assert" - then [read up on it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert).

Comment: I'm doing it right now ;)

Comment: it's look like I can do it with static_assert and std:is_class< T >, I'm going to try it

Comment: "I would like "resource_t" be a class that implement class X and Y" - Still not clear for me. `X` and `Y` are classes? Template argument of `resources_t`? Are related to `ServiceInterface` and/or `Libraries::Observer`/`Libraries::Observable`? And what do you mean with "a class that implement class"?

Comment: Yes it is, this two other classes are in fact AbstractResource and LoadableInterface, "resource_t" must implement them.

Comment: Maybe I understand: do you mean that `X` and `Y` should be base classes for `resources_t`?

Comment: yes, X and T must be base classes for resource_t

Comment: Use `std::conjunction` together with `std::is_base_of`, in addition to `std::enable_if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two different ways.

You can accept every template parameter and then check (maybe with `static_assert()`) that `T` derive from `X` and `Y`

```
template <typename T>
class foo
 {
   static_assert(    std::is_base_of_v<X, T>
                  && std::is_base_of_v<Y, T>, "!" );

   // ...
 }
```

This way, if you declare a `foo` class with wrong arguments

```
foo<int>  fil;  // compilation error
```

you get an hard error (and the compiler report you `!`, that is the content of the second argument of `static_assert()`; this can be useful for debugging purposes).

Otherwise you can use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

By example

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
class foo;

template <typename T>
class foo<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<X, T>
                           && std::is_base_of_v<Y, T>>>
 {
   // ...
 }
```

This way, calling `foo` with wrong parameters, you get only a soft error (`foo<int>` isn't enabled)

With this way, you can implement another version of `foo` that is implemented when `T` isn't a derived class for both `X` and `Y`.

Comment: I just tried the first way with success, I'm looking for your second solution.

Comment: Yes, it works both way, I just had to remove the comma before "&&" in your solution. Thank you !